# Can you static link satellite assemblies?

Tags: c#, .net, localization, static-linking, satellite-assembly

I don't know enough about satelite assemblies to understand their construction, I'm curious if it's possible to statically link them all into a single dll and get the same functionality as if they weren't statically linked from:

```
ResourceManager.GetString("SomeStringIdentifier", CultureInfo.GetCulture(someCultureThatYouHaveResourcesFor));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they would have type collisions in the resource space which is all that's in a satelite assembly.